# Issue when connecting from Spark 2.2.0 to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, connector

My problem is about connecting from Apache Spark to MongoDB using the official connector.

Stack versions are as follows:

- Apache Spark 2.2.0 (HDP build: `2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235`)
- MongoDB 3.4.10 (2x-node replica set with authentification)

I use these jars:

- [mongo-spark-connector-assembly-2.2.0.jar](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/tree/r2.2.0) which i tried both to download from [Maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mongodb.spark%7Cmongo-spark-connector_2.11%7C2.2.0%7Cjar) and to build by myself with a proper [Mongo Driver version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/project/Dependencies.scala#L23)
- mongo-java-driver.jar downloaded from [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.1)

The issue is about version correspondence, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702377/mongodb-spark-connector-py4j-protocol-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-cal) and [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12223/mongodb-spark-connector-py4jprotocolpy4jjavaerror.html).

They all say, that the method [was renamed](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16786/files) since Spark 2.2.0 so i need to use the connector for 2.2.0 version - and yes it is, [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/r2.1.1/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/MongoInferSchema.scala#L135) is the method in spark connector 2.1.1, and [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/r2.2.0/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/MongoInferSchema.scala#L135) is renamed one in 2.2.0

But i am sure, that i use the proper one. I did these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark.git
cd mongo-spark
git checkout tags/2.2.0
sbt check
sbt assembly
scp target/scala-2.11/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar user@remote-spark-server:/opt/jars
```

All tests was OK. After that i am using pyspark and Zeppelin (so deploy-mode is client) to read some data from MongoDB:

```
df = sqlc.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .option('spark.mongodb.input.uri', 'mongodb://user:password@172.22.100.231:27017,172.22.100.234:27017/dmp?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&connectTimeoutMS=300&readPreference=nearest') \
    .option('collection', 'verification') \
    .option('sampleSize', '10') \
    .load()

df.show()
```

And got this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, worker01, executor 1): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.TypeCoercion$.findTightestCommonTypeOfTwo()Lscala/Function2;
```

I think am sure this method is not in the jar: `TypeCoercion$.findTightestCommonTypeOfTwo()`

I go to the SparkUI and look at the environment:

```
spark.repl.local.jars   file:file:/opt/jars/mongo-spark-connector-assembly-2.2.0.jar,file:/opt/jars/mongo-java-driver-3.6.1.jar
```

And no different MongoDB-related files anywhere. 
Please help, what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was the filecache... helped this advice https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150578/how-to-clear-local-file-cache-and-user-cache-for-y-1.html